# Can't get check box options to change depending on value of collection_select in a rails 3.2 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-3.1

I have a form in rails 3.2 for creating users in a company. Each company has sites. A site is assigned to a user via a collection_select, and then each site has a number of departments which are selected using check boxes. A user belongs to a site and can belong to many departments from that site.

I need the department check box options to change dependant on the selected value in the sites collection_select.

I have been trying to do this by using :onchange of the collection_select to call a partial containing the departments. I've managed to get this to work but only displaying all departments for the company. Not departments for each individual site. I don't understand how to pass the selected site to the partial so it can return the correct departments (if this is even possible).

My code so far is:

Form:

```
    <%= form_for @user, :url => front_admin_users_path do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

      <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>

      <%= f.collection_select :site_id, current_user.company.sites.all, :id, :name, {}, :onchange => "jQuery.get('/load_department')",  :remote => true  %>

      <div id="department_frame"></div> 

      <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

      <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

users_controller.rb:

```
     def load_department
       respond_to do | format |  
         format.js {render :layout => false}  
       end
     end
```

load_department.js.erb:

```
    $("#department_frame").html( "<%=j render(:partial =>"department") %>" );
```

_department.html.erb:

```
    <% current_user.company.sites.each do |site| %>
<% for department in site.departments %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[department_ids][]", department.id, current_user.department_ids.include?(department.id) %>
    <%= department.name %>
<% end %>
```

I have googled for days trying to find the solution but can't find exactly what I need. The nearest thing I've found is Ryan Bate's dynamic collection selects revised using the grouped_collection_select method (which I've used in another part of the project), but this doesn't seem to deal with select boxes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try passing the `site_id` as a parameter in the `URL` to the AJAX call and then read that value off in the `controller`.  In the `controller` method, you can also then get the list of `departments` for that particular `site` and then pass that off to the `view` that is being rendered.

I have edited the relevant parts of the code to explain what I mean better.  Hopefully this makes sense :)

Form

```
<%= f.collection_select :site_id, current_user.company.sites.all, :id, :name, {}, :onchange => "jQuery.get('/load_department?site=' + $('#user_site_id').val())",  :remote => true  %>
```

users_controller.rb:

```
def load_department
    site = params[:site]
    @departments = Site.find(site).departments

    respond_to do | format |  
        format.js {render :layout => false}  
    end
end
```

_department.html.erb:

```
    <% for department in @departments %>
        <%= check_box_tag "user[department_ids][]", department.id, current_user.department_ids.include?(department.id) %>
        <%= department.name %>
    <% end %>
```